# Basic HTML cross-browser bugs in IIS?

Tags: html, iis, cross-browser

I'm simply bewildered. I tried to set up my basic HTML website in IIS and am getting 3 different results between the main browsers. (It's supposed to look like Chrome's display.) They all work locally, but through "mycompname/website/default.html" it does what you see below. Thanks.

[image]

---

HTML (As per request)

```
<html>
<title>Website</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/clean.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Page Load Functions
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
        $('#menu ul li ul').hide(); // Hides submenus

        // Hides submenus
        $('#menu > *').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#menu ul li ul').slideUp('slow');
        });

        // Shows submenu
        $('#menu > ul > li > a').hover(function(){
            if(!$(this).parent().children('ul').is(':visible'))
            {
                $('#menu ul li ul').slideUp('slow');
                $(this).parent().children('ul').slideDown('slow');
            }
        });

        $('#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if($(this).attr('href') != '#')
                $('#main').load('content/' + $(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Put fancy logo here.</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="test.html">SubMenu Item 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 1-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 1-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 1-5</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a>menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 2-5</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a>menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item 3-5</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a>About Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2012 xxx. All rights reserved.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Also refresh and show the output of Firebug Console...

Comment: By default IIS won't molest vanilla html in any way, this is much more likely to be an issue with your markup, what is it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Firebug says: $ is not defined | [Break On This Error] | $(function() {

Comment: See if `scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js` is accessible or not? There seems to be permissions issue... :(

Comment: For me, it seems that the problem relies inside the CSS files (especially when looking at the FF version). Could you post them too?

Comment: Also you should check the error console in your browser, I guess that you will find some hints there.

Answer (score 0):

See what is the HTTP Code you are getting? Check it out here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380

Are you hosting the site on iis? if so make sure the account your website runs under has access to local file system?

Straight from msdn .....

> The Network Service account has Read and Execute permissions on the IIS server root folder by default. The IIS server root folder is named Wwwroot. This means that an ASP.NET application deployed inside the root folder already has Read and Execute permissions to its application folders. However, if your ASP.NET application needs to use files or folders in other locations, you must specifically enable access.

To provide access to an ASP.NET application running as Network Service, you must grant access to the Network Service account.

To grant read, write, and modify permissions to a specific file

- In Windows Explorer, locate and select the required file.
- Right-click the file, and then click Properties.
- In the Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.
- On the Security tab, examine the list of users. If the Network Service
- account is not listed, add it.
- In the Properties dialog box, click the Network Service user name, and in
  the Permissions for NETWORK SERVICE
  section, select the Read, Write, and
  Modify permissions.
- Click Apply, and then click OK.

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx) for more

Comment: This didn't have any effect. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Coz mainly I asked for getting the status code in Firefox, when you try to load the CSS files. It should be either 403 or 404. Its purely permissions issue and try giving `Users`, the permission of `Full Access` for the folder `C:\Inetpub\WWW`, hope this at least helps!